# MYSQL Innodb: Composite Primary Key and Reverse Search

Tags: mysql, innodb, composite-primary-key

I am creating an event to user lookup table using the Innodb search engine.

Table Event_Users

```
event_id
user_id

Index (PRIMARY) -> event_id, user_id
Index (secondary) -> user_id, event_id ??
```

The application will search user to event and event to user. How do I define the second index if the primary key is clustered? Should it simply be `user_id` and then MYSQL will figure out that event_id is already present in the PK or should I be redundant and include `user_id, event_id` in the secondary index?

In addition, is this a good use of a clustered index? Any guidance and help with Innodb clustered indexes would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what is `secondary` index btw?

Comment: Normal non-unique index. Nothing special but it will be utilized just as much as the PK

Comment: if you keep the secondary index as a composite, then it can serve as a `covering index` if you don't need to retrieve additional columns.

Comment: I did some additional research and MySQL SHOULD be able to use the fields in the PK as a covering index without making a composite secondary index.  Composite secondary index can greatly slow down insertions and updates. The table will be heavy read/write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL should be able to use the fields in the PK as a covering index without making a composite secondary index.

Therefore:

Table (Engine = INNODB)

```
column_a  (int)
column_b  (int)

Primary Key -> column_a, column_b
```

If you would like to search by `column_b` simply add index: `column_b`.

Since the table using the Innodb engine, the PK will exist in the `column_b` index. Mysql will be able to use the index (using index). No need to create index `column_b, column_a` as this would be redundant. - Remember, inndob clusters by PK and all indexes reference the PK.

A surrogate key is a poor choice for this design because extra work would have to be made to ensure `column_a, column_b` does not already exist.

Comment: If you only use single compound index `(column_b, column_a)` (primary key or not), you do not need to add index `(column_b)` - MySQL will make use of it when searching by `column_b`. But, you need to have index on `(column_a)` for lookups by `column_a`. So, if you propose to have just single index `(column_b,column_a)`, this solution is incorrect.

Comment: That is correct but I made an error. Primary key should read -> `column_a, column_b`. I have fixed it now.